# I am looking for a better term than "hidden and unwanted or damaging"

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, titles

I am looking for a  particular term used to express something that is `hidden and unwanted or damaging`. I would like to use this expression to coin a title that goes as: `Unveiling <suggested term here> in ....`.

Comment: ______Termites?

Comment: Pandora's box? Don

Comment: Can you give more context, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go for...

**"unveiling a nemesis"**

nemesis - A source of harm or ruin [TFD](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/nemesis), an opponent or enemy that is very difficult to defeat [Merriam-Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/nemesis?show=0&t=1417995161)

Answer (score -1):

***"Unveiling detrimental secrets in"***